# Возможно вывести .vue в статическую .html страницу?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

На странице index.html есть `<div id="#app"></div>` куда рендерятся все файлы `.vue` расширения , возможно ли вывести вместо `<div id="#app"></div>`статическую  `html` страницу т.е `header` `footer` 'всё то что прописано в `<template></template>`? пользуюсь `webpack`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/, достаточно настроить плагин [`prerender-spa-plugin`](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) в `webpack`, также можно воспользоваться готовым фреймворком [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)